# Guardar archivos de forma asíncrona con Ajax y c# (webmethod)

Tags: c#, ajax

Cuando ejecuto la función subirArchivos no llega al método del lado servidor.
Cual es la mejor forma de guardar archivos?
mi código javascript.

```
function subirArchivo(event) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('adjuntarOC', event.files[0]);
    formData.append('id', ($(event).closest("tr"))[0]['id']);
    formData.append('campo', event.dataset['ruta']);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'Principal.aspx/subirArchivo',
        data: formData,
        //contenType:'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        //datatype: 'json',
        success: function (r) {
            console.log(r);
            obtenerProyectos();
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

En el lado servidor.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string subirArchivo()
{
    var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0];
    return "ok";
}
```

Puse el retur **ok** solamente para probar si llegaba al método.

Comment: Tu pregunta no esta muy clara, que exactamente es lo que quieres? Te ocurre algun error?

Comment: Jose, realmente no hiciste una sola pregunta y dado que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, es posible que tu publicacion resulte en espera o cerrada si no la editas.

Comment: Ya lo edite :). Espero que me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Donde deseas guardar tu archivo, mira según yo, estas enviando un `data`, entonces tienes en el `webservice` que recibir ese `data` .

Mira te dejo un ejemplo de como yo hago una llamada `ajax` a un `webservice`, espero te pueda ayudar y puedas resolver tus dudas.

```
function searchProduct() {
    var idproduct = $('#idp').val();
    //Ahora hacemos un llamado AJAX, a un metodo del WebService (searchProduct) para poder recuperar los datos
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../WebServices/ServiceProduct.asmx/MethodSearchProduct",
        data: "{ IDProduct:'" + idproduct + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {

        },
        error: function (errormessage) {
            alertify.warning("Problemas al recuperar los datos");
        }
    });
}
```

Y este es mi `webservice`

```
[WebMethod]
public object MethodSearchProduct(string IDProduct){
       object result = new object();
       result = ObjConnectorProducts.findName(IDProduct);
       return (ProductsDAO)result;
}
```

Esa es mi manera de llamar a un `webservice` desde `ajax`

O bien mira te dejo un ejemplo de como yo guardo un archivo json en mi disco duro

```
public int SaveObjectJSON(object list, string name){
int i = 1;
JavaScriptSerializer JS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var jsonList = JS.Serialize(list);
// Create a folder
string folderName = @"C:/Data";
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:/Data/" + name + ".json", jsonList);
return i; 
}
```

En el cual recibo un `object` con formato `json`, ademas de un nombre el cual sera el nombre del archivo.

Comment: Lo que quiero es guardar archivos. como haces cuando quieres guardar archivos o fotos. Como lo envías desde lado cliente al servidor? Me podrías ayudar con un ejemplo de esa naturaleza? muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira con fotos nunca lo eh probado, pero acabo de editar el código y te puse un ejemplo con un archivo `json`, espero y te pueda servir.